# htaccess causing infinite loop with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I would like to reirect `/wp-login.php` to `/login` 
I added this line to /htaccess and the redirection works .

```
RewriteRule ^wp-login.php$ http://wesbite/login  [NC,L]
```

Now when a user enter his login/password in the page `/login` , even when the user's login/password are right he is always redirected to the same page `/login` without being authenticated .

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^login$ http://yourdomain/wp-login.php [NC,L]
```

http://www.yourdomain.com/login/

Comment: I would like to redirect wp-login to /login and not the inverse, I think that what you wrote do the inverse. Please correct me if I'm wrong.